# Angular custom Validator

Tags: angular, custom-validators

i am trying to make a custom validator in angular cli 4.5.5
Some parts of my form only need to be validated when a checkbox is checked.
i don't seem to get it working. Here is my validator code:

```
export function validateCheckbox(control:AbstractControl){
const val = control.value;
const check = control.root.get('checkbox');

if (check) {
    if (val === null || val === undefined || val === '') {
        return {
            validateDays: {
              valid: false
            }
          };
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}else{
    return null;
}
}
```

Here is my component code:

```
    @Component({
    selector: 'caredeal-registration',
  templateUrl: './registration.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./registration.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})

export class RegistrationComponent implements OnInit {
  registerForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name:['',Validators.required,Validators.minLength(2)],
      firstName:['',Validators.required,Validators.minLength(2)],
      email:['', Validators.required,Validators.minLength(2)],
      telephone:['',Validators.required,Validators.minLength(9)],
      mobilePhone:['',Validators.minLength(10)],
      type:[''],
      checkbox:[false],
      companyName:['',Validators.minLength(2)],
      rizivNumber:[''],
      taxNumber:['',Validators.minLength(2)],
      streetName:['', Validators.required],
      houseNumber:['',validateCheckbox],
      bus:[''],
      zipCode:['',Validators.required,Validators.minLength(4)],
      place:['',Validators.required,Validators.minLength(2)],
    })
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

My html code:

```
<form [formGroup]="registerForm" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit()">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <h3>Account informatie</h3>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="name" placeholder="Naam">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="firstName" placeholder="Voornaam">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" formControlName="email" placeholder="Email">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i></span>
                        <input type="tel" class="form-control" formControlName="telephone" placeholder="Telefoon">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i></span>
                        <input type="tel" class="form-control" formControlName="mobilePhone" placeholder="GSM">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <label for="sel1">Type klant:</label>
                        <select class="form-control" formControlName="type">
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                            <option>4</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <h3>Bedrijfsgegevens</h3>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="companyName" placeholder="Bedrijfsnaam">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control"formControlName="rizivNumber" placeholder="RIZIV-nummer">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="taxNumber" placeholder="BTW-nummer">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <h3>Afleveradres</h3>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-road"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="streetName" placeholder="Straatnaam">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-sound-5-1"></i></span>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" formControlName="houseNumber" placeholder="Huisnummer">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-inbox"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="bus" placeholder="Bus">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-inbox"></i></span>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" formControlName="zipCode" placeholder="Postcode">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-inbox"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="place" placeholder="Plaats">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="checkbox" formControlName="checkbox"  name="">Facturatie adres is verschillend van afleveradres<br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <button type="submit" [disabled] = "!registerForm.valid" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

</form>
```

My checkbox is in the end of my html code.
At the moment i am getting this error:
Expected validator to return Promise or Observable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your problem is not related to your custom validator. You are passing certain validators as async validators while they are not async.

Please take a look at [FormControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl) constructor documentation.

Try replacing lines like `email:['', Validators.required,Validators.minLength(2)],` with `email:['', [Validators.required,Validators.minLength(2)]],`

Comment: This fixed the error. Now my validator is having some issues. It is now always required to fill in the Housenumber(Custom validator used here). and it schould only be required when the checkbox is checked. Thanks for already fixing the error!!!

Comment: @JorenVermeir I'm sorry but this is not a chat (welcome on SOF by the way), if my answer helped you can accept it, and post another question that details your new problem